# How to block access to all VSTS accounts except our work VSTS account

Tags: security, azure-devops

My company want to get VSTS. But they do not want users to be able to access their personal VSTS accounts at work. They are concerned that users will upload source code to their personal VSTS accounts and download it at home. Or worse, they are worried that users can upload a virus to their personal VSTS account, come into work and download it. I'm sure everyone will understand why they want to do this.

Without getting into ethical reasons about how companies need to trust employees etc......They want to stop this or reduce this as much as possible.

Is there any guidance on how to achieve this?

One solution is to maybe block *.visualstuido.com but whitelist only our company VSTS account? This is messy because there will be a bunch of other visualstudio.com urls that we will need to access such as {accountname}.vsrm.visualstudio.com.

There is no way for us to know all the urls that we will need to allow access if we block *.visualstudio.com

any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Wrong place for this. This is a programming q&a site, and this question has nothing to do with programming. And definitely not the place to post about how you and your company distrust the programmers who work for you, or make assumptions about how everybody will understand why you're doing it. Also please do not abuse tags (such as `ms-access`).

Comment: it's a legitimate question. Just asking for advice. No need to get so defensive.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Stack Overflow is for questions about programming and **tools commonly used by programmers**, which includes VSTS. That said, this really boils down to an issue of network configuration and belongs elsewhere for *that* reason.

Comment: @DanielMann - This question has nothing to do with how to work with a programming tool. It's about user access blocking for a specific online service (well outside the scope of the tool) - which is precisely why it is off-topic here. But... the topic of not trusting employees? Completely superfluous and shouldn't be included, whether posted here, SuperUser, or elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you read the question clearly, I specifically say "Without getting into ethical reasons". i.e. not talk about that subject.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can achieve it. There are many ways that can store/download the source code except VSTS, such as github. Users also can upload/download the source code through email. So you can’t prevent them to do it unless block to access internet.

The simple way is that:

1. Build an intranet network
2. Clone VSTS repository to a shared folder
3. Others work with that repository (commit changes to that repository)
4. Push changes to VSTS by yourself or build the app to track repository and push commits automatically.